# Limiting the axes on a mplot3d surface without the graph spilling from the figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes, mplot3d

I'm attempting to make a 3D surface plot of a spectrogram, but I want to limit the axes to a certain frequency and time range. I've tried the following:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
ax = mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D(fig,rect=(0,0,20,5),azim=-90,elev=10)
plot = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,norm=norm,vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax,cmap=cmap)
ax.axes.set_ylim3d(bottom=0, top=200) 
ax.axes.set_xlim3d(left=-5, right=40) 
fig.colorbar(plot)
plt.show()
```

as well as `xlim()`/`ylim()`, and `set_ylim()`/`set_xlim()`. For some reason, when I try to limit the axes, the graph [spills over the edge like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhAar.png).

[The graph without axis limits for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDnGA.png)

How do I avoid this?

Comment: There is no clipping performed in 3D, so you are responsible yourself for only plotting the data that you want to see in the image.

Comment: Oof, okay. Thank you so much!